# How to combine multiple selectable in jqueryUI

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, selectable

```
<div id="selectable">
    <div>
        <p><span>content</span> <span>1</span></p>
        <p><span>content</span> <span>2</span></p>
        <p><span>content</span> <span>3</span></p>
        <p><span>content</span> <span>4</span></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p><span>content</span> <span>5</span></p>
        <p><span>content</span> <span>6</span></p>
        <p><span>content</span> <span>7</span></p>
        <p><span>content</span> <span>8</span></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p><span>content</span> <span>9</span></p>
        <p><span>content</span> <span>10</span></p>
        <p><span>content</span> <span>11</span></p>
        <p><span>content</span> <span>12</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: HTML is not in control.

How do I apply jquery selectable to all `<p>` located inside different `<div>`.
and all the `<p>` should work like as in same `<div>`. 
Example

```
<div id="selectable">
    <div>
        <p><span>content</span> <span>1</span></p>
        <p><span>content</span> <span>2</span></p>
        <p><span>content</span> <span>3</span></p>
        <p><span>content</span> <span>4</span></p>
        <p><span>content</span> <span>5</span></p>
        <p><span>content</span> <span>6</span></p>
        <p><span>content</span> <span>7</span></p>
        <p><span>content</span> <span>8</span></p>
        <p><span>content</span> <span>9</span></p>
        <p><span>content</span> <span>10</span></p>
        <p><span>content</span> <span>11</span></p>
        <p><span>content</span> <span>12</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#selectable > div').selectable();
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcvt9qwp/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `filter` option.

**[Docs for filter option](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#option-filter)**

```
$("#selectable").selectable({
  filter: "p"
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6k5m6gdn/)**

Comment: @Jitu: glad it helps. just in case if you want multiple selectable  then refer here http://jsfiddle.net/oL1efx02/

Comment: what if I have <table> along with <p> in that <div>  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/6k5m6gdn/1/)

Comment: Actually my requirement is that if there is a table then that entire table should be selected. refer this   http://jsfiddle.net/6k5m6gdn/1/

Comment: this is selecting entire table.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this css [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/wcvt9qwp/1/)

**Css**

```
 #selectable div p  { background: #F39814; color: white; }
```